# Why is an array inside a template string displayed as a normal string?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Let's assume we have an object:

```
var pet = {
      "name": "Barky",
      "species" : "dog",
      "foods": {
        "likes": ["bones", "carrots"],
        "dislikes": ["tuna"]
      }
    };

console.log(pet.foods.likes);        //returns [ 'bones', 'carrots' ]
console.log(`${pet.foods.likes}`)    //returns "bones,carrots"
```

If I use template string, it is displaying as a normal string, why?

Comment: As You are getting the string interpretation of an array.

Comment: Because you're building a string? Why would you expect the template string to be displayed as something else?

Comment: @Bergi, here the data type of likes is an array. It is not a string.

Comment: @iamPavan `likes` might an array, but the data type of the result of the template literal evaluation is a string. Don't wrap the array in a string if you want to keep it as an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the template literal, the expression inside gets implicitly coerced to a string (because template literals always evaluate to strings). So, the array gets `.join`ed by commas as part of the interpolation process, and becomes a string (without `[]`s, and without string delimiters between items).

```
console.log(`${pet.foods.likes}`)    //returns bones,carrots
```

is equivalent to

```
console.log(pet.foods.likes.join(','))
```

or

```
console.log(pet.foods.likes.toString())
```

In contrast, the plain `pet.foods.likes` is an array, and so gets logged as an array with array delimiters.

Comment: ... or in any way the console wants to log it.